# Simple Lightbox Plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, lightbox

I am using the Simple Lightbox Plugin for Wordpress and the lightbox seems to shift everytime it reloads an image. Does anyone know what causes this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean shift? Do you have an example?

Comment: http://devo.terra.softfocus.com/coachs-concepts/

Comment: I'm super new to wordpress. Where would I actually insert this? I tried the default CSS...but it doesn't seem to take...?

Comment: I changed my answer a small bit. Try adding `!important` after the margin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `.loading` class, there is a margin that is causing it shift:

```
margin: -14px 0 0 -42px;
```

Changing that margin to:

```
margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
```

should fix it. The style below is with the corrected amrgin

```
.loading {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```